# Como convertir url de texto plano a cliqueable? (PHP)

Tags: html, mysql, php7

tengo esta función que hace lo que debe hacer

```
// Enlaces automático
      $postData['post_body'] = preg_replace('@(https?://([-\w\.]+[-\w])+(:\d+)?(/([\w/_\.#-~]*(\?\S+)?)?)?)@', '<a href="$1">$1</a>', $postData['post_body']);
```

pero, el problema es que si existe una imagen (url), me devuelve esto

```
<img src="<a href=" https:="" media.discordapp.net="" attachments="" 647462329058983972="" 647465408928153611="" install.png"="">
```

o en un `<code><pre><script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer></script></pre></code>` me devuelve esto

```
<script src="<a href="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js"">https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js"</a> async defe></script>
```

y lo que quiero es que se eviten esas etiquetas.

Espero haberme explicado bien, y desde ya muchas gracias!

Comment: Pareciera que el contenido ya tiene HTML incluido con URLs, no solo texto, asi que convertira todas sin importar si es contenido o atributos. Puedes mostrar un ejemplo del contenido de `$postData['post_body']` ?

Answer (score 1):

Ya que el contenido tiene mezcla de texto con URLs y URLs incluidas en atributos HTML, la unica manera de distinguir los links *text-only* es procesar el contenido como un documento HTML (usando [DOMDocument](https://www.php.net/manual/es/class.domdocument.php) y recorrer los nodos usando [xPath](https://www.php.net/manual/es/class.domxpath.php))

Este es un ejemplo bastante completo basado en otra respuesta que encontre [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4003031/how-to-replace-text-urls-and-exclude-urls-in-html-tags).

```
<?php

$html = '
<html>
<body>
<p>
    Link dentro de una etiqueta A: <a href="http://example.com/1">link</a>.<br>
    Otro link dentro de etiqueta IMG: <img src="http://example.com/image.jpg">.<br>
    Link sin etiqueta: http://example.com sera convertido a etiqueta.
</p>
</body>
</html>';

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$xPath = new DOMXPath($dom);
// obtener los nodos solo-texto que contengan links
$texts = $xPath->query(
    '/html/body//text()[
        not(ancestor::a) and (
        contains(.,"http://") or
        contains(.,"https://") or
        contains(.,"ftp://") )]'
);
// recorrer los nodos de texto y reemplazar URLs
foreach ($texts as $text) {
    $fragment = $dom->createDocumentFragment();
    $fragment->appendXML(
        preg_replace(
            "~((?:http|https|ftp)://(?:\S*?\.\S*?))(?=\s|\;|\)|\]|\[|\{|\}|,|\"|'|:|\<|$|\.\s)~i",
            '<a href="$1">$1</a>',
            $text->data
        )
    );
    $text->parentNode->replaceChild($fragment, $text);
}
// obtener el html procesado/reemplazado
$html_out = $dom->saveXML($dom->documentElement);
echo $html_out;
?>
```

El resultado sera:

```
<html>
<body> 
 <p>
Link dentro de una etiqueta A: <a href="http://example.com/1">link</a>.<br/>
Otro link dentro de etiqueta IMG: <img src="http://example.com/image.jpg"/>.<br/> 
Link sin etiqueta: <a href="http://example.com">http://example.com</a> sera convertido a etiqueta. 
 </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hola, gracias por responder! Pero por desgracia no me ha servido, pero si me sirvió el enlace de donde lo has obtenido ya que esa página me llevó a otra página donde encontré lo que necesitaba [PHP Reg ex for parsing a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4239425/php-reg-ex-for-parsing-a-link) ... Muchas gracias por tomarte tu tiempo para responderme!